Adobe JavaScript- Check a box if the date entered is older than 365 days
I am trying to create either a Validation Script or a Javascript Action in Adobe.
I need to check a box called CheckBox2 is the Date entered in DORMANT is greater than 1 year old from Today's date.
So if Date entered is 06/02/2021 then the box would be checked.
I have googled so many things and not found an answer that works.
Any help would be great.
Thank you

Create a Date object that contains the date 365 days ago. Parse the date in DORMANT. Compare these two dates, and check the box according to the condition. Which part of this are you having trouble with?

Writing that.  I am not good with Javascript.   The date in the DORMANT field will change when form is ran.  And which field do I put the validation on?

// Get the value of the DORMANT field
var dormantDateStr = this.getField("DORMANT").value;

// Parse the date entered in the DORMANT field
var dormantDate = util.scand("mm/dd/yyyy", dormantDateStr); 
//ensure the date format here matches the date in your field DORMANT

// Get today's date
var today = new Date();

// Calculate the date one year ago from today
var oneYearAgo = new Date();
oneYearAgo.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() - 1); 


// Check if the dormant date is more than one year ago
if (dormantDate < oneYearAgo) {
    // Check the CheckBox2
    this.getField("CheckBox2").checkThisBox(0, true);
} else {
    // Uncheck the CheckBox2 if the condition is not met
    this.getField("CheckBox2").checkThisBox(0, false);
}

getFullYear
Also, you could add this as a JS script in Adobe instead of a validation script, can be triggered when DORMANT is filled and loses focus etc.
Adobe Acrobat > Tools > JavaScript > Document JavaScripts > Add
